# Postman with miltiple params on Web Api C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm having a problem with this technology,

I already have created a entry in my web api controller that allows me to create users:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostUser(User user)
```

and I can consume this rest service with postman like this:

[image: Post using Postman]

Now I want to create a similar entry but this time with 2 parameters, like this:

```
        public IHttpActionResult PutUser(int id, User user)
```

**MY PROBLEM IS THAT I CAN'T REACH THIS METHOD WITH POSTMAN**

I already try:

- Add my "id" parameter on postman heather
- Add my "id" parameter on postman body-form-data
- Add my "id" parameter on postman body-x-www-form-urlencoded
- Add my "id" parameter on postman body-raw befor and after the json code using as separator ['&' , ','] and as asignation char [':', '='].

none of these worked and I ran out of ideas.

does anyone knows how to invoke this service properly ?

best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add attributes to your method, as such:

```
public IHttpActionResult PutUser(int id, [FromBody] User user)
```

This indicates the `user` parameter is received from the request body. Next, you can use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:15423/api/users?id=<your_id>
```

And in favor of full on REST use, if you add `[FromUri]` to the `id` parameter, and a `[Route("{id}")]` to the method, you could use:

```
http://localhost:15423/api/users/5
```

Where `5` can be replaced by your id.

(Both requests should include the `User` object in the body)

Comment: Hi Eavidan, thanks for your answer, this is routs config:             config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

adding  [FromBody]  doesnt solve my problem, the post keeps going to the method `putusers` without id...

Comment: No need for that, of you add the Route attribute to the method, the Route should be available. You should read about attribute routing in Web API. Either way, the first suggestion should work.

Comment: Hi! you were right, I read about attribute mapping and finally I was able to solve my problem. regards!