# Postman using Put

Tags: c#, json, api, postman, url-parameters

Trying to do Put using Postman, can't seems to figure it out:

I have this method, which triggers a break point and everything is good:

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(User user)
{
    // ... code ...
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

In a Postman:

```
url:          .../api/users/2 
Headers(1):   Content-Type application/json, 
Body: 
     {
          "id": "1",
          "login": "Test",
          "pass": "1"
      }
```

... the usual stuff, etc ...

It works, but **NOW** I need to change the method to

```
public IHttpActionResult Put(int key, User user)
{
    // ... code ...
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

I tried everything in a body of message using Postman, nothing makes it trigger the break-point. How do I have that key passed in along with user object???

Needed to add [FromBody] also because my routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}" is like this, I changed method definition from key to id, that way I can call Put using the following url .../api/users/3

Comment: try `url:          .../api/users`

Comment: Sounds like you want to add `[FromBody]` to the user parameter. See [WebAPI Multiple Put/Post parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14407458/215552), which appears to ask the same question as yours...

Comment: Or possibly this one: [Postman with miltiple params on Web Api C#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39681590/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [FromBody].  The following is the working code which I use with HttpPost

```
[HttpPost("ByYear")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetStudentDetailByYear([FromBody]SearchStudentModel model)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.query)
       || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.AcademicYearID))
       return BadRequest("Required Parameter not provided");

      // some codes to handle the query
 }
```